# event.preventDefault(); when trigger is parent div not link?

Tags: jquery

I have a div as a trigger for some jQuery. The div contains a link. Sometimes clicking the div will also mean clicking the link and I need to stop the link's behaviour.

I believe this can be done with event.preventDefault(); but the following doesn't work in IE8. Im assuming this is because the trigger is a parent div not the actual link, but how do I fix this? Thanks

```
$('div#myDiv').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //other js here
});


<div id="myDiv">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define the parameter:

```
$('div#myDiv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //other js here
});
```

`.preventDefault` is a jQuery shim in the jQuery event object. It doesn't exist in the IE event object.

Chrome and IE define a global `event` object which refers to the native event object in those browsers. For this reason, always use `e` `ev` `evt` etc so you don't accidentally refer to this global event object as it won't get the jQuery bug fixes and normalizations.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: So do you think adding `e` as a parameter would help?

Comment: Yeah http://jsfiddle.net/4kwgD/. The default action is only made after the event has fully travelled its propagation path and wasn't prevented .

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution probably can be to remove the `href` attribute on the anchor tag. though i dont recommend this but can be a quick solution.