# Javascript event, the parameter "e" , "event" or other

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/kent93/9UNyH/):

```
var transformString = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');
var inputDown, inputMove, inputUp;


if (window.Touch) {
  inputDown = "touchstart";
  inputMove = "touchmove";
  inputUp = "touchend";
}
else {
  inputDown = "mousedown";
  inputMove = "mousemove";
  inputUp = "mouseup";
}

var mouse = { startX: 0, startY: 0 };
var innerElement = $('.threedee');

function normalizedX(event){
    return window.Touch ? event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : event.pageX;
}    

function normalizedY(event){
    return window.Touch ? event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY : event.pageY;
}

$(document).bind(inputDown, function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if(event.button === 2) return true; // right-click
  mouse.startX = normalizedX(event);
  mouse.startY = normalizedY(event);
  // store the transform state
  // globalMatrix.setMatrixValue($inner.css('-webkit-transform'));
  $(document)
   .bind(inputMove, move)
   .one(inputUp, function(){ $(document).unbind(inputMove); });
});

function move(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var offsetX = normalizedX(event) - mouse.startX;
  var offsetY = normalizedY(event) - mouse.startY;
  if(event.shiftKey){
   offsetX = roundToMultiple(offsetX, 15);
   offsetY = roundToMultiple(offsetY, 15);
  }
  innerElement.css(transformString, 'rotateY('+offsetX+'deg) rotateX('+-offsetY+'deg)');
  /* move relative to the initial position
  $inner.css('-webkit-transform', globalMatrix.rotate(-offsetY, offsetX, 0));//*/
}

function roundToMultiple(number, multiple){
  var value = number/multiple
  ,   integer = Math.floor(value)
  ,   rest = value - integer;
  return rest > 0.5 ? (integer+1)*multiple : integer*multiple;
}​
```

Try to look at the javascript part only, my problem is there.

I am wondering why the "event" will pass as parameter and argument for most of the function in the script. Sometime it may be "e" also. Who created them???

I myself never created any "event" variable, who is responsible for this "event" variable.

Comment: Google is your friend.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery will call your event function and it will pass an event object into the argument. You don't need to worry about creating the variable, and you can give the argument any name you want (assuming it's a valid variable name).

The creation of the event object should be considered "black box", and you shouldn't worry about its exact structure or implementation. Just do what the docs and examples show you to do, and you'll be all right.

The key thing is to have a parameter in the function, though; otherwise, you won't have access to the event object jQuery passes.

As some other answers have stated, it's probably a good idea to avoid the name `event`, because if you're not careful you could conflict with a global variable of the same name on certain browsers. Instead, use `e` or similar and then you'll get a `NameError` if you forget to have a parameter in your function.

```
// Wrong way #1
$('.class').bind('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();    // may attempt to call .preventDefault() on window.event if it exists
});

// Wrong way #2 (fails fast since e probably won't be on the global object)
$('.class').bind('click', function() {
    e.preventDefault();        // ReferenceError thrown here
});

// The correct way
$('.class').bind('click', function(e) {    // or (event) if you want, but the first example can bite you
    e.preventDefault();        // no problem
});
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery passes a normalized, bug-fixed and featurized [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to your handler function as the first parameter. You should name this parameter `e` (or similar) so you never accidentally refer to the global `window.event` (Which is the native event object in chrome and IE) and get a quick error instead.

Comment: If it's named `event` in the function argument list, then using the `event` variable in the function will ALWAYS refer to the argument, with the global being shadowed. The only issue can occur if the argument is misspelled.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I understand that, I meant if you forgot the formal parameter, you wouldn't get a fast error in that case but would implicitly refer to the global one. Just earlier today I answered a question where this happened.

Comment: Here's the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11845355/995876 The bug doesn't appear until you debug your app in IE where as if one had used `e`, it would have failed fast in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

The functions that reference `e` or `event` are callback functions. They are essentially called by jQuery itself and pass a variable as a result (you define the function there, but it calls it, assuming it's defined). That's why it can be either defined as `e` or `event` (it could be `purple_elephant` too).

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)