# Is it necessary to specify parameter "e" in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

There are a number of functions in jquery that use the parameter `e` to access some of the things or to do somethings like preventing the hyperlink from taking action using `e.preventDefault()` is it necessary for us to define or specify `e` in the parameters of the function?

For e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This works even when I didn't specify the variable of the parameter `e`.

So my question is, does it make any difference if we specify the parameter `e` or not?

Comment: See this answer to somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852794/1668421

Comment: This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Comment: @Danijel Can you post a jsfiddle please? My doubts are extremely high that `e` will be available and assigned to `arguments[0]` in *any* browser.

Comment: @HenryBlyth I expect `window.event` might be, but as you say, not `e`.

Comment: @Henry Blyth, you are right, event works but not e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to (and indeed must) specify `e` (or `ev`, or `event`, or whatever you want to call it) if you want to access properties or methods of it.

This wasn't *always* the case - older IE versions had a global `window.event` variable that MS used instead of passing a parameter, hence why you sometimes see native JS code written like this to cope with either model:

```
function handler(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    ...
}
```

JavaScript will ignore passed parameters that aren't in the functions formal parameter list, although they'll still be available via the `arguments` pseudo-array.

Similarly, any formal parameters that don't have values supplied by the caller will have a value of `undefined`.

Comment: Since we're talking about jQuery, we don't have to worry about IE not passing the event object to the handler. See the [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/): *"jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler.*" But an upvote to you for bringing that to light as I didn't know this previously =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

`e` is the event object. If you have an element like this:

```
<a href="/somewhere.html">Click me</a>
```

then your javascript will execute, then the event will bubble up, and the page will change. If you aren't including a `href` attribute, the click event is still 'happening' but the link doesn't go anywhere anyway.

Cancelling the event stops the redirection (or submit, if you're talking about a form, etc).

If you leave the argument out, the event object is still accessible in the `arguments` variable, so you can still recover it later on in the function if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `e` isn't written in stone. It's what some developers name the event object, which is the first parameter passed to event handlers according to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/). You may name it what you like.

You may come across some code that calls methods on an object named `e`, but it may not be an event object. Check the call to which you are giving the handler so you can determine what is expected of it.